# weird behavior using "redirect back" and 2 or more tabs with Laravel 5, only on Server

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, http-referer, referer

i have a big and weird problem using Laravel 5.4 on shared hosting.

When laravel use "redirect back", it redirect to the last visited page.

Let's imagine this:

We have a site with 2 sections: Products and Categories. 
We visit the products page and the url is **site.com/products**. This page have 3 buttons, new, edit and gallery.

We want to edit the producto with ID 3 (**.../products/3/edit**) so we edit its information and save it. No problems here, validations were oK.

BUT we need to edit again the product so we go to edit page (**.../products/3/edit**). The name field accepts max 10 letters but we typed 11. We open the categories page on a **different tab** (**../categories**). Then we press the "save" button but validation will fail because the name field have 11 letters.

And booom! **Laravel redirect to the categories page** because that was the last opened page but it should redirect us to the **edit page**.

This happens if i use a "form request validation" ( public function update(ExampleRequest $request){...} )

or if i use a simple request validation 
( $request->validate(['title' => 'max:10, ...]); )

Both examples have the same problem.

In other hand, working with controllers, if i use **return redirect()->back()...** or **return Redirect::back()...**, the same behavior happens, it redirect to the last opened page.

So, When i'm creating, updating, deleting, etc, if the validation fails or if i use redirect()->back(), this will redirect me to the last opened page and if i opened a page in another tab, that page will be where the "redirect" will send me. If i use only 1 tab, everything works fine.

This happens with all my forms and **only on the server**, the local environment is ok.

Now, my code:

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    # To switch to PHP 7
    AddType application/x-httpd-php56 .php

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Controller

```
use App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest;

public function update(ProductRequest $request, $id)
{
  $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
  $product->update( $request->all() );

  $msgResponse = [...message...];

  return Redirect::to('/products')->with($msgResponse);
}
```

ProductRequest

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class ProductRequest extends FormRequest{

  public function authorize(){
    return true;
  }

  public function rules()
  {
    return [
      'title' => 'required|max:10|...',
      'otherfield' => ['required', Rule::in([...]),],
      ...
    ];
  }
}
```

**Site:**

PHP 7.0, Shared server, Laravel 5.4

Please help! :(

**MORE INFO**

As @Aken Roberts said (or typed =p), the problem is the **Referer header**

I tried to check what is sent to the $request using **dd(...)** :

```
public function xxx(Request $request, $id){
      dd($request);
      ...
```

In my **local environment**, the current URL is received inside **server**, **headers** and **session** :

```
+server: ServerBag {#42 ▼
    #parameters: array:29 [▼
      ...
      "HTTP_REFERER" => ".../products/3/edit"
      ...
...
..
+headers: HeaderBag {#44 ▼
    #headers: array:12 [▼
      ...
      "referer" => array:1 [▼
        0 => ".../products/3/edit"
        ]
      ...
...
..
#session: Store {#409 ▼
    ...
    #attributes: array:4 [▼
      ...
      "_previous" => array:1 [▼
        "url" => ".../products/3/edit"
        ]
      ...
```

The *session* object may change if a visited another page in a different tab but that's not a problem with the local environment because we have the **HTTP_REFERER** and **referer**

But on the **server**, *HTTP_REFERER* and *referer* do not exist, only the **url** inside **session**.

So i have to find why it is happening that. I don't want to add the specific url for every form, validations, etc 〜.〜

I'm not sure but, i thinking of looking for a new hosting, maybe digitalocean, linode, and add a SSL Certificate, because i had to do some changes to use a shared hosting (i followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_3112267529&feature=iv&src_vid=E8NlzSjqMpM&v=KdWsQh3prqE), min 5:43 ), but that's an extra cost for the client.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's validation, Redirector, and anything else that determines the previous or "back" URL all utilize the same logic. The [`Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::previous()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/30d2f7f350e1e5bfa742e18e993deedefec2e953/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L138-L157) method first checks if a Referer HTTP request header exists - if so, it uses this URL. If not, it checks for a special "previous URL" session value that Laravel saves on each request where sessions are enabled, and uses that.

Based on your explanation, it seems the Referer header is not being sent or recognized, and Laravel is falling back to the previous URL session value. One possibility according to the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer):

> A Referer header is not sent by browsers if an unsecured HTTP request is used and the referring page was received with a secure protocol (HTTPS).

Beyond that, I'm uncertain what would cause the Referer to be missing/ignored.

I can, however, suggest that you don't rely on Laravel's previous/back functionality, and instead be explicit in what URLs you want to redirect to whenever possible.

For a Form Request, it's very easy. There are three different properties you can choose from to set the redirect URL:

```
/**
 * The URI to redirect to if validation fails.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirect;

/**
 * The route to redirect to if validation fails.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectRoute;

/**
 * The controller action to redirect to if validation fails.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectAction;
```

For other more "automagic" solutions, an invalid request usually results in a thrown `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException`. You can catch this, and modify it by adding a `redirectTo` URL:

```
try {
    $request->validate([ /* rules */ ]);
} catch (ValidationException $e) {
    $e->redirectTo(route('route.name'));
    throw $e;
}
```

Would be nice to have to avoid using this in multiple places, so I hope you can get to the bottom of the Referer issue!